# Selenium C# chromedriver with DesiredCapabilities

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests

I would like to implement DesiredCapabilities with a chrome driver instance in C# but from what I can find it isn't possible? For example...

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.UnexpectedAlertBehavior, "accept");               
Driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\Development\Projects\SeleniumObservatoryTests\", capabilities);
```

ChromeDriver seems to require Options. Is there a way to provide UnexpectedAlertBehavior as an Option?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to add a capability with the following:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.UnexpectedAlertBehavior, "accept");
```

You can also ignore the alert:

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();

options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.UnexpectedAlertBehavior, "ignore");
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to get it to work either for Chrome.  For Firefox I had to use DesiredCapabilities and for IE I had to use InternetExplorerOptions.

BUT, I have been successful at handling the popup with Chrome, with some code I wrote to handle it.

My code is posted below.  I hope it helps you and whoever else plagued with Modal dialogs.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Returns a true or false if alert is present.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>true or false</returns>
    public static bool IsAlertPresent()
    {
        try
        {
            [YOUR DRIVER HERE].SwitchTo().Alert();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Verifies if an alert is present or not.  If it is, it clicks "Accept".
    /// </summary>
    public static void Alert()
    {
        try
        {
            if (IsAlertPresent())
                [YOUR DRIVER HERE].SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ///Log your errors however you must.
        }
    }
```

I know it's not fancy or anything, but it gets the job done.  Basically it tries to switch to an alert, if it's there it returns true, if it's not it returns false.  If true, it switches again and clicks accept.  Very simple.  Hasn't failed me yet.

Comment: Hi. Actually I am using pretty much exactly the same code as a workaround. However when switching iFrames now and again one creeps through. So I had to do a "waitForAlerts" on top of this which is basically a forced wait for a few seconds to catch any unexpected alerts. Not ideal but okay for now.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is how it is done for the WebDriver 4.x .NET bindings...

```
var options = new ChromeOptions();
Dictionary<string, object> browserStackOptions = new Dictionary<string, object>();
browserstackOptions.Add("unhandledPromptBehavior", "ignore");
options.AddAdditionalOption("bstack:options", browserStackOptions);
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).